# How and why does gradle from("originPath") and into("targetPath") delete's files?

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a gradle task, which takes one directory and copies it into another directory.

`from({ framework.outputDirectory }) into(File("/Users/user/Desktop/"))`

here is full gradle.kts task

```
val generateIOSArm64Framework by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "iosArm64"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(File("/Users/user/Desktop/"))
}
```

I thought it will just copy's `framework.outputDirectory` into `Desktop`, but when I run that task it deleted all my files which were on Desktop (including some non backuped project). I can't restore those files.

**Question**: why gradle `into` delete's files? does it creates new folder every time and override's everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is not of type `Copy` but of type [`Sync`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Sync.html):

> This task is like the `Copy` task, except the destination directory will only contain the files copied. All files that exist in the destination directory will be deleted before copying files, unless a `preserve(Action)` is specified.